# Is there a Non COM API for iTunes

Tags: c#, api, com, itunes

I need to access iTunes data (playlists, songs etc.) in a C# application, but without using the COM interface available from Apple..

The problem i have is that the iTunes COM interface requires the iTunes process to be running. I would like to avoid that and make my application work even if iTunes process is shutdown.

I need only read-only access to GET some simple data from the iTunes database and not any kind of real-time control and similar.

Is there a way to suppress the iTunes process from starting automatically when i use the COM objects or is there an alternative to the COM interface?

I see that for apple developers it is normal to access an XML file, and they just recently got access to a "Library Framework"

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/iTunesLibrary/Reference/iTunesLibraryFrameworkReference/_index.html

I could probably access the same XML file in windows.. is that the only alternative approach? or is there something more elegant?

Comment: [Why? What problem are you having?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/34397)

Comment: i have added an explanation above

Comment: I just nead read only access.. i have found C++ apps that access iTunes data (read-only) without running the process. I wonder how to do it in C#, or even in C++.

Comment: I think you suggested the answer to your own problem. [This KB article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1660) indicates that the purpose of the XML file you mentioned is to share data with other applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is definitely to use the XML file since i have found other software that does the same.